# Using Webbrowser object on inactive windows session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webbrowser-control

I'm currently using the .net WebBrowser object in a console application to navigate to a webpage, click on a button and then get the page HTML after that button click. This have worked great on local machine where the console application is executed in a active Windows Session.

Now i want to move the functionallity that the console application does into my asp.net web api service. But this doesn't work. When i try to run the code on the web server the iis process takes all cpu and RAM and keeps doing that until i kill the iis process manually.

I'm thinking that the WebBrowser object can not be used without an active Windows Session. Am i correct about this?

How do i solve my problem where i want to move the console application functionality to my web api service?

I figured that i could use HttpClient to call the URL, but that won't work because i need to click a button before i have the HTML i want to download.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
Log.Info("Setting up webbrowser thread.");
ThreadStart browserThreadStart = () =>
    {
        Log.Info("Staring web browser");
        using (var browser = new WebBrowser { ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true })
        {
            Log.Info("Go to URL.");
            browser.Navigate(Url);

            Log.Info("Wait for browser");
            WaitForBrowser(browser); // <-- Here the IIS process on the webserver goes crazy on CPU and RAM

            Log.Info("Click button");
            //Added this line, because the final HTML takes a while to show up
            var isCheckbox = browser.Document.GetElementById("buttonid");
            isCheckbox.InvokeMember("click");

            Log.Info("Wait for browser");
            WaitForBrowser(browser);

            Log.Info("Return html");
            result = browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
        }
    };

Log.Info("Starting thread for webbrowser.");
var browserThread = new Thread(browserThreadStart);
browserThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
browserThread.Start();
browserThread.Join();
```

Comment: You can use WebBrowser but it needs to be launched in its own STA thread. I don't understand why you can't use HttpClient. How is the button click preventing the use of HttpClient?

Comment: I'm allready launcing it in its own STA and it does not work. Do you have any webpages with examples on how it works? I can use HttpClient but i would get the wrong HTML because i need to press a button in the browser before i get the rigth HTML. When the button is click it makes a async call to server to get new data.

Comment: Nothing that I can show you. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644433/how-to-click-a-button-in-an-webpage you could use something similar to trigger button click on the HttpClient.